# How can a model (user) has only one other model (eg workplace), but the workplace belongs to many users in Sequelize.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I would like to have one model (that's the user) that belongs to **one** other model (that should be the workplace), but the workplace (e.g. Apple) should have many users that belong to them. How can I do that using Sequelize?

I already tried to use one `User.hasOne(models.Workplace)`, but this only allows each Workplace to have one User, because it creates the column `UserId` in the Workplace table.

This is the code of my user model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const User = sequelize.define('User', {
        id: {
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        username: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        firstname: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        }
    }, {})

    User.associate = (models) => {
        models.User.hasOne(models.User)
    }

    return User
}
```

And this is the code of my workplace model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Workplace = sequelize.define('Workplace', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        }
    }, {})

    return Workplace
}
```

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's think about this problem in lower level.

I assume you use some kind of relational database since you're using Sequelize on top of it.

Your requirement is that user has only one other model (eg workplace), but the workplace belongs to many users.

It can be translated into `user` model has foreign key `workplaceId` in their table and `workspace` has no foreign key in their table.

For example, `{ userId: 1, workspaceId: 1 }, { userId: 2, workspaceId: 1 }, { workspaceId: 1 }` would be what you expected.

How can we achieve this?

Just set `belongsTo` relationship in `user` model.
(It generates `workspaceId` in your table)

It's always good to think in database layer first because after all `Sequelize` is just an abstract layer for that.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer! Yes, you are right, but my user should also have other relations than workplace. Can I add multiple ```belongsTo``` statements to the user model?

Comment: Why not? belongsTo and hasOne are functions just adding foreign key into the target table, in this case user.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for this perfect solution. You really solved my problem! Thansk!